# Is the build environment passed to GDB when launching GDB in Eclipse (CDT)?

Tags: gdb, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I thought the answer was yes, because all worked fine on the PC I was using.

I had the following environment variables:

- CYGWIN_HOME = "C:\cygwin64"
- PATH = "${CYGWIN_HOME}\bin;..."

(These variables are automatically set when selecting Cygwin as a tool chain for the project.)

And, in Debug Configurations -> Debugger, I set GDB debugger to: gdb (without specifying the full path.)

I left the corresponding setting empty in the workspace settings (Windows-> preference->C/C++->Debug->gdb)

I also made sure that the actual Windows PATH did not have "C:\cygwin64/bin" in it.

I was able to run GDB in Eclipse (CDT) without any problem, and with all of the above, the only way Eclipse could get the GDB location was from the build environment.

I recently tried to install the same setup on another PC, but this time GDB would not work. Eclipse fails to find it and complains on the very first command (gdb --version), but it compiles fine though and Make is able to find all the UNIX command it needs (rm for clean, for example), which makes me think that this time the build environment only applies to the build process, not the debugger.

Is there any setting that need to be specifically adjusted for the debugger to use the build environment?

I'm running Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) with Cygwin.

Comment: If your path on that machine has any empty elements (something;;something) make that something;something.

Comment: @dbrank0 Thx. That was the issue, but the ";;" was not in the actual Windows path. It was in the Eclipse generated project environment path created from the Windows path. Among other things, Eclipse appends ";C:\Program Files\eclipse" at the end of the Windows path. It works ok, on the first setup but on the second one, it actually appends ";;C:\Program Files\eclipse" which is where the issue is. It looks like it is an Eclipse issue. (Note: the last element in this Windows path of the faulty setup is :C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\)

Comment: Just for the reference: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389823

Comment: The answer to my original question is: yes, the intended design of Eclipse is to run GDB in the build environment, and there is no specific setting for enabling or disabling this. What I encountered seems somehow related to the bug dbrank0 pointed at, with the difference that, in my case, Eclipse corrupted its own project environment path with a ";;". For more information on the symptoms I experienced, see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1083143/